# Restricting results included in SUM() with the condition in joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to list my product table but with a link to my delivery orders to give me sums of stock in certain statuses; allocations, dispatched etc

There is a 'status' field to define where an delivery is currently at eg; 1 = allocated, 2 = dispatched, 3 = delivered etc

This is as far as I have got so far

```
SELECT product.*, sum(quantity) AS allocated FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN delivery_product ON ( product.id = product_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN delivery ON ( delivery_id = delivery.id AND delivery.status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY code           
ORDER BY code
```

It includes all quantity matches from delivery_product whereas I only want to include those where the delivery order status = 1. I think this is because i am joining to the delivery_product table first before the status restriction kicks in but how else can I do this?

Bonus points if you can see a much better way to approach my task altogether :)

-

```
product
id  code   stock
1   ABC    1000
2   DEF    2000

delivery
id  status   date   etc
1   1        etc    etc

delivery-product
id  delivery_id   product_id   quantity
1   1             1            500


results
product.id product.code product.stock allocated
1          ABC          1000          500
2          DEF          2000          0
```

Comment: Post some sample data and desired output....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a small modification to your query should work:

```
SELECT product.*
,   sum(case when delivery.status = 1 then quantity else 0 end) AS allocated
FROM product 
    LEFT JOIN delivery_product ON ( product.id = product_id ) 
    LEFT JOIN delivery ON ( delivery_id = delivery.id AND delivery.status = 1 ) 
GROUP BY code           
ORDER BY code
```

You could avoid the conditional by converting the `delivery` join to inner from left outer, but the query would not return rows with `quantity` of zero if delivery records with the status of `1` are missing for the product.

Comment: This works perfectly mate. Also simpler for me as I can add each status total as its own sum with another case! great